# How can I serialize backbone model into URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to store state of a simple application in a model, and be able to generate URL containing full state of the application (i.e., serialized model). Is there a backbone-idiomatic way to provide such a feature?

**Related:**

- [BackboneJS model.url using collection.url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461264/backbonejs-model-url-using-collection-url)
- [Backbone.js state management / view initialization based on url fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127154/backbone-js-state-management-view-initialization-based-on-url-fragment)

Comment: I think [Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) is what you need

Answer (score 1):

Backbone let's you serialize models to JSON but not to URL parameter syntax.  You *could* stringify the JSON, url encode it, and then add it to the uRL ...

```
var json = yourModel.toJSON();
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
var encoded = encodeURI(jsonString);
var url = 'www.example.com?model_json=' + jsonString;
```

... but I wouldn't recommend it.  URL parameters were never designed to be used that way, and you can run in to lots of problems.  One problem is character length limit.  As [this Stack Overflow answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), urls need to be limited to 2000 characters to be safe.  Depending on what you put in your model, you could certainly exceed that without meaning to.

A much better approach would be to save the model somewhere that's designed to hold it, like on the server (that's exactly what the `save` method of a `Backbone.Model` is for, after all) or in local storage.  Then, all you need to put in the URL is the model's ID, and you can use that ID to retrieve the data remotely/from local storage.